# What is the type of *args if args is not provided

Tags: python

I was trying to implement map function in Python and I came across this:

```py
def map(func, iterable, *args):  
    for args2 in zip(iterable, *args):
        yield func(*args2)
```

I wrote down a few tests to check if it's working correctly.

```py
from types import *
print(isinstance(_map(None, None), GeneratorType))
print(list(map(lambda x: x.upper(), 'just a line')) == list(_map(lambda x: x.upper(), 'just a line')))
print(list(map(lambda x,y: x+y, [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])) == list(_map(lambda x,y: x+y, [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])))
```

But this got me thinking, what is happening here:

```py
print(list(map(lambda x: x.upper(), 'just a line')) == list(_map(lambda x: x.upper(), 'just a line')))
```

I provided only iterable argument. So in this case:

```py
iterable = 'just a line'
args = Not provided
```

What in this case is the value of *args? Is it even an object? What it is? When I'm trying to print values

```py
print(args) - > ()
print(len(args)) -> 0 
print(*args)) -> 
print(len(*args)) ->  TypeError: len() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Comment: `print(type(args))`?

Comment: `*args` is not an object, it's just special syntax for passing multiple arguments to a function. `args` is an object of type `tuple`.

Comment: if nothing provided it is an empty `tuple` or `list`

Comment: @rioV8 What do you mean `tuple` ***or*** `list`? It has a definite type which is `tuple`

Comment: @Tomerikoo It is an iterable you are not supposed to modify or modify the elements, so it does not matter if it is tuple or list, it has `[]` operator defined

Comment: So if ```args``` is not provided. ```zip(iterable, args)``` it's not iterating because args is an empty sequence.  ```zip(iterable,*args)``` is not getting the second argument at all? It's will only iterate over ```iterable```?

Comment: @rioV8 well you're kinda overcomplicating stuff... `args` is simply a tuple which consists of all the extra positional arguments passed. The `*` before the `args` means it packs all those arguments into said tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure out the type by using `type` function, but the main problem here, I think, is that you're treating `*args` as an object which is certainly not the case.

`*` is just an operator, so when you want to use function like `len` or `type` on it, you should use `args` without `*`.

To answer your question, it's always a `tuple`.